# Is my WiFi card broken

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, drivers, wifi-driver

I got one Intel ATOM mini laptop without any brand name, this was sample from China(looks a lot like an Acer Aspire One). Until a day or two ago it was on WinXp an WiFi card worked well and I was able to connect to networks.

After removing some viruses with a virus remover the WiFi suddenly stooped working. Our first thought was that the virus remover also removed the WiFi driver so I installed Win7 instead.

But without success, I see WiFi adapter and can change properties of it but the adapter can't see any networks. I also thought that wlan adapter is turned off by hot keys Fn+F1 and I try switching it OF ON by pressing combination but also without success.

I also tried to boot laptop with Ubuntu OS but the problem remains. I see wlan card but no networks.

When I open device manager my WLAN card is registred as RT73 USB Wireless LAN card and there is no other unknown devices shown in list.

What could it be?
Any idea ?